# Email Signature App Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am making an email signature application that allows user to make signatures and use them to send with emails, Their is signature name(Text Field), content(Text View) and image(Image View) and i am saving them in Database so that if the user selects the signature name from the table view that is on the second view the preview will show up on the same view like if i select signature 1 from table view then in preview section the signature image should show up with the signature content in (Text View), and then on the same view we press send(Button) the text and image from the Text View of preview section will be copied to clipboard and then in third view i can paste it in the message section and send the email, is it possible to do that if yes how can i implement it or any other idea how to do this ?

Comment: Sorry but that sounds like "I've got an idea for an App, but no clue how to do it. Could you write the code and send it to me?". Don't expect any helpful answers to such a question. Try something, use your head and feel free to ask again…

Comment: @LionKing just use this bellow method from one view to send email with message and image in the MailComposeViewController you can see the message and image so here not required another view for send email.. see my answer bellow..

Answer (score 0):

i have this one method for send email with image and message .. just add `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` in .h file and add framework `MessageUI.framework` in your project

```
-(void)sendMailWithImage:(NSString *)message Image:(UIImage *)image{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
    {
        UIImage *tempImageSave=image;
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *mailBody = message;

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImageSave);
        [mailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Testing"];
        [mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:mailBody isHTML:NO];
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } 
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"e-Mail Sending Alert"
                                                        message:@"You can't send a mail"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

and this bellow method is delegate method of `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`

```
#pragma mark - MFMessage Delegate

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) 
    {
        NSLog(@"\n\n Email Sent");
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

i hope this help you...